# How to fire $watch to call alert and console.log only once each type inputed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I am trying to call only once each time the watch group is called upon to fire the console.log and alert only once. Because I am trying to alert only once each time if the condition is true, I really hope you guys can help me out!

```
$scope.$watch('email.data', function(val){
  if(re.test(val)){    
    $scope.invalid = true;
    console.log('email true');
  }else{
    console.log('email false');
  }
});

$scope.$watch('phone.data', function(val){
  if(PHONE_REGEXP.test(val)){
    console.log('phone true');
    $scope.invalid = true;
  }else{
    $scope.invalid = true;
    console.log('phone false');
  }
});
```

Comment: Consider using `ng-change` instead of a `$watch`

Comment: can you give me an example on how to use ng-change?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.$watch` returns a function. if you call it you remove your watcher

```
var emailDataWatcher = $scope.$watch('email.data', function(val){
  if(re.test(val)){    
    $scope.invalid = true;
    console.log('email true');
  }else{
    console.log('email false');
  }

  emailDataWatcher();
});

var phoneDataWatcher = $scope.$watch('phone.data', function(val){
  if(PHONE_REGEXP.test(val)){
    console.log('phone true');
    $scope.invalid = true;
  }else{
    $scope.invalid = true;
    console.log('phone false');
  }

  phoneDataWatcher();
});
```

Comment: Hi alex is not working after I type in each time the alert button will keep on appearing everytime i type in a word

Comment: See updated code, I moved the de-registration to outside of the if. If its still not working, please post where this code sits. You need to call it only once and not for every type

Comment: Erm alex the code is working fine but when I try to add different symbol on email address it logs out error but the button still become valid and still visible but if I didnt add the remove watcher thing my code works fine why is that happening ya?

Comment: Don't think its related, just coincidence. Your whole work around `$scope.invalid` looks weird. I think you wanted to set to `false` when `phone true` and `email true` and `true` otherwise ?

Comment: You can add a working fiddle of the code if you want a closer inspection

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3or9748t/ here this is the link to my code on roughly how does it works

Comment: Hi @AlexD are you there?

Comment: Ya I know is a ionic app actually because of that I dont know how to upload the full file to it. By the way alex can you give an example on how to use ng-change to solve this issue?